# i'm unable to find the problem in my java code

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to learn java on my own, the following code does not compile.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Strings> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        cars.add("Volvo");
        cars.add("BMW");
        cars.add("Ford");
        cars.add("Mazda");
        System.out.println(cars);
        cars.set(2, "Maruthi");
        System.out.println(cars);
        System.out.println(cars.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(cars.get(i));
        }

        System.out.print("Names: ");
        ArrayList<Strings> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner();
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; i++){
            cars.set(i,input.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

The above code gives me this error.i'm unable to find the problem in the code.

Comment: _"The above code gives me this error"_ - what error? If you get a compilation error, you should add it in the question. If you have an exception during runtime, you should add exception message and if so possible its stacktrace.

Comment: You haven't given an error, but this `ArrayList<Strings>` is suspicious. Is that a typo? Because it should be `String`

Comment: Your loop looks suspicious as well, for example - `for(int j = 0; j < 5; i++){` that `i++` should be `j++` and `cars.set(i,input.nextLine());` should be `names.add(input.nextLine());` (because you don't do anything else with `cars` - you print `names` and your variable is `j` not `i` and you are adding to a new `List`).

Comment: You cannot set an entry in an ArrayList beyond the current size of the ArrayList, among the other errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your array list parameters must be String not Strings, then in your second for loop you switch variables from j to i, for loop variables are only accessible from within the loop. And your scanner also takes in a paremeter, if getting input from console do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: i aslo changed " Scanner input = new Scanner()" to "Scanner input = new Scanner(system.in)". Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Here is compilable code. It works but still throws an exception in execution which you need to handle

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        cars.add("Volvo");
        cars.add("BMW");
        cars.add("Ford");
        cars.add("Mazda");
        System.out.println(cars);
        cars.set(2, "Maruthi");
        System.out.println(cars);
        System.out.println(cars.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(cars.get(i));
        }

        System.out.print("Names: ");
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            cars.set(j,input.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```